# Why might CPU Usages and Threads be goes to 99-100%?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I load a table view, and I'm performing no activity intentionally
except letting the table view show, I'll wait a few seconds and then
my CPU usage shoots up. How can I find the cause?

Instruments says around 3% of CPU time goes to `cellForRowAtIndex` method, with that one being the most consuming method. Of that 3%, 75% goes.

It's dependent to RAM and device memory.... I have to manage according to device .

Answer (score 0):

Check what happens on the simulator. If the simulator uses hundred percent, it's a bug in your code. If the simulator uses say 20-30%, it might be your app has lots of work to do.

Simplest way is trying to press "pause" in the debugger and see what code is executing... If your app takes 100% and you think it should do nothing, chances are that pressing pause will stop right in the code that shouldn't be running.

Comment: I have to use tableview methods (Cell etc.) after is completed then goes to 100%..

Comment: This problem after create 200 rows in tableview. and received to memory warning..